# No results when running powershell script in ssis foreach container

Tags: sql-server, powershell, foreach, ssis, etl

Couple of things to make note of.

Powershell is in unrestricted mode so adding `ExecutionPolicy` bypass is not needed.
Runs successfully when i hard code the variable filename and then set up argument below in `Execute Process Task`.

```
@[User::Script_url] + " " + @[User::filename]
```

But once I place that `Execute Process task` in `Foreach loop container`, to feed a different filename, nothing happens except the powershell opens and then closes quickly for the number of files in that directory...which suggests it is feeding the variable to the parameter but not actually executing the powershell script with each filename.

Comment: Use 4 spaces to format code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the variable mapping Tab in the foreach loop, it looks like you didn't mapped your variables correctly. Also make sure that you are **not selecting** the `Fully qualified` option in retrieve file name Group box. because the expression you are using `@[User::Script_url] + " " + @[User::filename]` need only to retrieve the `Name and extension`

[image]

Comment: @missy if this answer solved your issue, you have to accept it, just click on the mark below the voting arrows https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work