# use case to 'Name and Extension', 'Full Qualified' and 'Name Only' options in foreach file enumerator in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I am trying to find the use case scenario for when to use

1. Name and Extension
2. Fully Qualified
3. Name Only

while importing flat-file type files from source in SSIS.

Would anyone help me understand the use case scenario for each of the 'retrieve file name' types?

Thank you for giving your valuable time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are looping over text files stored within a directory `C:\My_Files\`. The following table shows how the file enumerator retrieve the filename using each option:

| Option | Example | Use case example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fully Qualified | `C:\My_files\example.txt` | [Importing data from multiple files into an SQL databases](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-load-multiple-files-to-table-with.html) |
| Name Only | `example` | Executing a conditional task based on the file name. For example, adding a task that checks the file name, then using [precedence constraints](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-ssis-precedence-constraints/) to execute a Process Task based on the file name |
| Name and Extension | `example.txt` | [Importing data from multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102868/no-results-when-running-powershell-script-in-ssis-foreach-container/48103200#48103200) - Executing a conditional process task based on the file name and extension - Copying/Moving files from one directory to another one and keeping the file name |

This option is selected based on the logic you are trying to implement. I highly recommend referring to the following article for more details:

- [SSIS ForEach Loop File Enumerator](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-foreach-loop-file-enumerator/)

Comment: Thanks for responding, Hadi...  my concern is to find some with respect to the use case scenario for each of the 'file name' types implementation in the real time.

Comment: @TechchampPgm I updated my answer and added some examples.

Comment: Name and Extension is useful when you have the directory as a variable (I'll call it [@directory]) and you want to move the file after processing and keep the name. [@directory] + "\\archive\\" + [@fName]

Comment: @KeithL That's a good example. I will add it

Comment: Hadi (and other  enthusiastic contributors),  I got one concern left over relevant to this thread; why do have to use the fully-qualified names? what could be common and or ideal scenarios?

Comment: @TechchampPgm the fully qualified name allows you to perform common tasks easier (read, write, copy, move ...).